# Static Wordpress Multi-Site Rules From Apache to Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I have been reading and trying things for 3 days, but I can't seem to get the right combination of rules to do what the Apache2 server did.

The Apache2 rules are:

```
RewriteRule ^/about/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/about/(.*\.php)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/about/(.*) /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Which simply detected the static slug `/about/`, and silently added a `/wordpress/` in front before passing to PHP.

With Nginx though, there's something that just isn't making sense in doing a rewrite AND passing the silent rewrite to PHP.

In Nginx I have:

```
location ~ ^/about/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) {
   try_files /wordpress/$1 =404;
}

location ~ ^/about/(.*\.php)$ {
   try_files /wordpress/$1 =404;
}

location ~ ^/about/(.*) {
   try_files /wordpress/index.php =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

For troubleshooting, all other location directives are commented out.

`/about/` - tries to download a binary file.

`/about/index.php` - tries to download a binary file.

`/about/wp-admin/` - Produces 404 not found.

PHP-FPM is working correctly when using a basic Nginx config. I think on the first two rules, it's not passing the rewritten URL to the backend. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ^~ /about/ {
    rewrite ^/about/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /wordpress/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/about/(.+\.php)$ /wordpress/$1 last;
    rewrite ^ /wordpress/index.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Once the rewrite rules have been applied, how does it get to the next block? After the rewrite, something isn't quite right in sending to PHP. it either goes to PHP and PHP sends back an empty page with 200 OK, or Nginx servers the PHP file as plain text. Is there some way to say `Go To @Wordpress` after the rewrites?